# SharePoint List Conditional Formula not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, power-automate, list-form

I'm having an issue with the SharePoint List conditional formula. I'm trying to show the Resignation with Notice field only when Job Movement Details = Resignation.

Below is the formula that I used which I have compared and check multiple times it is correct but I'm not sure why it still showing Enter a valid condition.

```
=if([$Job Movement Details]=='Resignation', 'true', 'false')
```

[image]

[image]

Your help are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I managed to found the issue. The issue was due to the naming, we need to follow the naming as below:

[image]

Go to list setting -> select the column name and check the naming at the end of link.